# PostgreSQL Script For Finding How Many Days Ago Someone Was Called

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql

I am working with PostgreSQL for the first time, and I am a little stuck on a task. I am trying to find out how many days ago someone, say a client in clients, was called from a call in calls. I have created a column in the client table called "lastcall" which I want to define as essentially NOW()-createdAt (where createdAt is a column in calls that is a timestamp with timezone). From what I see with the syntax this could be plausible, but I am not sure how to make it 100% legitimate.

```
SELECT lastcall (NOW()-A≥0) as T
FROM Clients
WHERE A is createdAt
FROM Calls
```

Any suggestions on turning this into reality are appreciated! Also, I believe we will need to sort the `createdAt` column, so that we can find the distance between the latest call and now -- which, I am also a little lost on.

The two tables in question here are `Clients` and `Calls`. Clients has 60 columns worth of attributes to describe a client, including a primary key id. Clients(id) is a foreign key to Calls for the column clientid. Calls has 7 columns, being `'id','clientname', 'clientphone', 'clientid','createdAt','updatedAt','overview'.` `'createdAt'` and `'updatedAt'` are timestamps with timezones. `'id'` is a primary key. No other columns are related, beside clientid and Clients(id).

Answer (score 0):

To get the current date in postgres, use CURRENT_DATE

Try something like this..(it assumes that there is a join column on Clients and Calls that associates both the table)

```
select current_date-lc.createdAt::date as T
from Clients c
inner join Calls lc 
on c.id=lc.clientid
```

Based on your update, if you are needing just the clientid and the last call, then you can do this..

```
select clientid,current_date-createdAt::date 
from Calls
```

Comment: Would clientid --> Clients suffice for a join column ? I have that, but I suppose by the error I got it does not. I received this error when trying this code: `ERROR:  relation "clients" does not exist
LINE 2: from Clients c
             ^

********** Error **********

ERROR: relation "clients" does not exist
SQL state: 42P01
Character: 50`

Comment: please describe your table and table columns and edit your original post. Thanks! Yes. clientid would be sufficient for a join column

Comment: Okay, I have wrote this as a  CREATE script for the column lastcall (I believe this is the proper way) and I receive this error `ERROR:  relation "calls" does not exist
LINE 2: from Calls
             ^

********** Error **********

ERROR: relation "calls" does not exist
SQL state: 42P01
Character: 52`

Comment: `-- Column: lastcall

-- ALTER TABLE public."Clients" DROP COLUMN lastcall;

ALTER TABLE public."Clients" ADD COLUMN lastcall integer;
select clientid,current_date-createdAt::date 
from Calls`

Comment: maybe its case sensitive? try select.. from "Clients"  or "Calls"

Comment: When I exchange Calls for Clients, I end up with this error: `ERROR:  column "lastcall" of relation "Clients" already exists

********** Error **********

ERROR: column "lastcall" of relation "Clients" already exists
SQL state: 42701`

Comment: Is there a define function in SQL? Because I could do  `-- Column: lastcall -- ALTER TABLE public."Clients" DROP COLUMN lastcall; ALTER TABLE public."Clients" DEFINE COLUMN lastcall integer; select clientid,current_date-createdAt::date from Calls`

Comment: what exactly is your objective...query or trying to drop/alter a column ? The right syntax to add a column of type integer is `ALTER TABLE tablename ADD COLUMN columnname int`

Comment: I am trying to define a column in Clients such that I can see how many days have passed since the most recent call from the table Calls. So, the value of lastcall will be integer but this integer is derived from current_date-createdAt

Comment: were you able to drop the existing column called lastcall ?

Comment: why do you need this column why cant you calculate the column on the fly using queries i provided...

Comment: Well, I am building a web app with node, angular, and postgresql. I am not sure of the complexity of calling queries on the fly vs just having a column pre-calculated to call whenever

Comment: What would you recommend?